# Selenium exception: "Component not initialized"

Tags: python, selenium

I encountered the following error:

```
[Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette
/content/dom.js :: addEventListener :: line 67"  data: no]
```

My code is as follows:

```
#loop by urls..
lnk = "http://" + urllib.parse.quote(url) 
try:
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,
                                executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe")
    browser.get(lnk)  
    time.sleep(random.randint(5,8))
    browser.minimize_window()
    print(browser.title)
except TimeoutException as e:
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        print(browser.title)
    except Exception as e:
        ...
except WebDriverException as e:
        print(str(e))
```

The error occurred frequently and I cannot understand what the error is about.

Comment: Hi Matt, Welcome to Stack Overflow. I doubt this is a Selenium issue however, can you add the full error stack trace for better debugging. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide full exception stack trace, and try browser cache clear then try again.

Comment: I turn no debug message by:  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET), but only get this info:  root:  Message: [Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/dom.js :: addEventListener :: line 67"  data: no]

Comment: And, I even try by: Re-install firefox, and restart system, the error still occur....

Comment: I bypass this issue by switching browser from Firefox into Chrome....